# How divide a folder of GIFs into animated and static ones

Tags: windows, file-management, gif

I have a folder with hundreds of GIF images. Some are static, and others are dynamic. How can I separate the static GIFs from the dynamic ones?

Comment: Since you want it for Windows, this is not a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752621/how-do-i-determine-if-a-gif-is-animated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a free tool called [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows). It can tell you how many images are in the GIF.

`identify -format %n~%f\n *.gif`

```
1~120406-00.gif
1~120406-01.gif
1~autonumbering.gif
```

%n   number of images in current image sequence

%f   filename (including suffix)

\n   newline

The 1 is front indicates how many frames are in the image.

Anything more than 1 we can assume is an animated GIF.

Comment: it doesn't work with non-ASCII names.
I'll try to check encoding.
but everything else is working fine, thanks

Comment: Sorry, I do not have any non-ASCII names to try out on my end.

Comment: It works!
Just encoding issue